# Receiving multiple tweets from Camel Twitter producer

Tags: java, apache-camel, twitter4j

With Apache Camel 2.15.0 I am trying to trigger a route which should retrieve the latest tweets of a certain user and send them to a consumer. Currently I am only able to produce a single exchange message with the latest tweet. How can I adapt this to return me a list of tweets?

The route is configured like:

```
from("direct:twitter")
    .pollEnrich("twitter://timeline/user?type=direct&user=${body}")
    .log("~~~~ tweet: ${body}");
```

Then the code which deals with payload which is send to the route looks like:

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:twitter", "BSchweinsteiger");
```